# react-monaco-editor text appears in middle of editor despite cursor being at the start of line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple react app to try and play with `react-monaco-editor`. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';
import './App.css';

const code = `
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>I mean really come one</span>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
`;

class App extends Component {

  onChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }

  editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    console.log('editorDidMount', editor);
    editor.focus();
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      selectOnLineNumbers: true
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MonacoEditor
          height="600"
          width="600"
          language="javascript"
          theme="vs-dark"
          value={code}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For some reason tho, the text in the editor is showing up in the middle, and my cursor is as the start of line as expected.

Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image: editor screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

This might be an old question but in React in the default App.css there is a line which sets the text-align to center.
If it looks similar to this:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #09d3ac;
}
```

you can just delete this part:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `editorDidMount` function with the last line like this:

```
editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    editor.focus();
    editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument')?.run(); // This line
}
```

The last will format the code document and set the cursor. Hope this will help.